# Refresh data in Power BI report once it's published without accessing Power BI desktop

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-datasource

I've built my first Power BI report and would like to publish it. Using my workspace I am able to do so successfully, and I can see the report and the data live.

[image: Report and dataset in power bi web]

Now I would like to hand over the report to a new maintainer. Unfortunately there is no API in place to retrieve data, so fetching new data will be a manual step. How do I proceed to set up the report in a way so that updating the report can be as simple as possible?

In the report I've combined several files using append query, due to the size limit of excel with 1 million rows. As the source data will be incrementally larger, updating the report in the Desktop view will take lots of time after a while, so I was hoping I could avoid using Power BI desktop to update the report and instead make use of the cloud resources in Power BI service (online).

Answer (score 0):

If you upload your files to a cloud location like SharePoint, OneDrive etc... then PBI service can refresh them online. If you do this, you will need to update your query slightly in Power BI desktop to get the files from the cloud as opposed to locally, after that you are good to go.